# Assembly reference naming conventions conflict between Xamarin Mac and Xamarin Forms for Windows

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I have some library that I have done and published in my own Nuget server. That library has a reference to [stateless](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stateless/) library:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="stateless" Version="4.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I'm reference this library in Xamarin Forms application for Windows stateless library downloaded in CamelCase as **S**tateless.dll

But when I'm trying to reference this library on Xamarin Mac application stateless library downloaded in lowercase as **s**tateless.dll.

And when I'm trying run this application in another Mac OS(not my own) I receive this error:

```
/Applications/TheAbyss.app/Contents/MacOS/TheAbyss ; exit;
ruslanmingazov@MacBook-Pro-Ruslan ~ % /Applications/TheAbyss.app/Contents/MacOS/TheAbyss ; exit;
2022-08-16 12:41:54.546 TheAbyss[10800:279461] Could not find `Stateless` referenced by assembly `Utils.Extensions, Version=1.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.
```

I'm trying to find solution but can't find anything.
Please help me.